# Centripetal forces acting on fluid flow in a bent pipe?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Yesterday I answered [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/208353/force-applied-to-a-90-degree-elbow-by-hydraulic-flow/208362#208362), using analysis of forces [from this web page](http://www-mdp.eng.cam.ac.uk/web/library/enginfo/aerothermal_dvd_only/aero/fprops/cvanalysis/node49.html).

But today I started having doubts regarding the *completeness* of this analysis. It occurred to me this approach does not take into account any centripetal forces caused by the changing direction of the fluid flow. Simply put:

$\vec{F}=m\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}$.

To analyse this, consider the following geometry for a $90^0$ bend in a pipe lying in a horizontal $(x,y)$ plane:

[image: Bent pipe.]

**Assumptions:**

- turbulent plug flow with constant fluid speed $v$, fluid density $\rho$, cross-section of pipe $A$, bend radius $R$.
- $\frac{R}{A}\gg 1$

Right now I am only concerned with centripetal forces needed to keep the flow on its rotational trajectory.

Take an infinitesimal element at $\theta$:

$dm=\rho A Rd\theta$.

The centripetal forces are:

$dF=-\frac{v^2 dm}{R}=-\rho A v^2 d\theta$

$dF_x=-\rho A v^2\cos\theta d\theta$.

$dF_y=-\rho A v^2\sin\theta d\theta$.

So these would be the forces the pipe needs to exert on the fluid:

$F_x=-\rho A v^2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos\theta d\theta=-\rho A v^2$.

$F_y=-\rho A v^2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin\theta d\theta=-\rho A v^2$.

If this is correct then I obviously need to amend my answer. **So my question is: is this correct?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same answer using momentum considerations.

In time $dt$ the amount of mass hitting the side of the pipe is:

$$dm=\rho A v dt$$

Now, we know that the force must satisfy:

$$F_{x}dt=dp=0-vdm=-\rho A v^2 dt $$

Dividing both sides by $dt$ gives:

$$F_{x}=-\rho A v^2$$

The force in the $y$ direction is the same as here.

Comment: Ah. That’s very interesting. I think the author of the second page I linked to also used momentum because $F_{x}=-\rho A v^2$ can be re-written as $F_{x}=-\dot{m}v$. That would mean my original answer was indeed correct. I will wait for any (?) more answers and then upvote. Many thanks!